# Detecting a pixel based on approximate color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am currently working on a AI for minesweeper and I am trying to detect the color of the numbers to see which number is there and I am having trouble finding the exact RGB code of it and when I print it it seems to change by slight amounts I am wondering if there is a way for to detect colors that are very similar to an RGB value? Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that R,G and B hold a value between 0 and 255. You can check if the value is close enough for you. Imagine you want to get a black pixel that is not completly black (10,10,10). You create a function that check if the pixel is between your tolerance. Between (0,0,0)# Black and (20,20,20) #Onyx

Comment: This should work, thanks!

Comment: @Fredericka so this is working pretty well the only issue I'm facing now is that one of the numbers color is very very similar to the empty space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was this:

```py
    def check_clicked(self, rgb):
        ok = str(rgb).replace("(", "").replace(" ", "").replace(")", "").split(",")
        r = int(ok[0])
        g = int(ok[1])
        b = int(ok[2])
        r_min = 205
        r_max = 220
        g_min = 175
        g_max = 195
        b_min = 145
        b_max = 163
        r2_min = 225
        r2_max = 235
        g2_min = 185
        g2_max = 205
        b2_min = 150
        b2_max = 170
        if (r >= r_min and r <= r_max and b >= b_min and b <= b_max and g >= g_min and g <= g_max or r >= r2_min and r <= r2_max and b >= b2_min and b <= b2_max and g >= g2_min and g <= g2_max):
            self.set_properties(0)
```

explanation:
I could not find the exact RGB value and sometimes they were inconsistent so instead I checked if the minimum/maximum fit in a certain range for each value and this solution worked and didn't create any false positives!

DISCLAIMER:
This solution will only work for a single-channeled color.

Comment: Rather than using one solid color, fonts are typically rasterized (i.e., converted from vectors to pixels) by using anti-aliasing. Be happy you're dealing with a single-channel color: For multi-channel colors, you'd also end up with flat-out wrong colors due to subpixel rendering.

Comment: Yeah I took this into consideration, luckily this doesn't apply to something as simple as minesweeper.